# Yocto - Can't build library for host SDK

Tags: embedded, yocto

I've made a custom recipe for a third-party library.
It contains:

```
BBCLASSEXTEND =+ "native nativesdk"
```

The recipe builds a static library, depends on `virtual/kernel` and copies some headers - relatively simple.

I'm trying to install this into the host SDK for cross-compilation, but I'm having some issues.

When I try adding:

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-<recipe>"
```

... to local.conf and run `bitbake core-image-weston -c populate_sdk`, BitBake completes, but the headers and library are absent from the host SDK (for my host's architecture).

When I try adding:

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " <package>-staticdev"
```

... I get the following error:

```
package <package>-staticdev-1.11.0-r0.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, your recipe depends on your build machine kernel? Shouldn't it be added in `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK` instead and based on target kernel?

Comment: @Nayfe Perhaps I misunderstand. The bb file contains DEPENDS = "virtual/kernel" as it relies on Linux headers during compilation. So it doesn't depend on the "build machine kernel", it just depends on the kernel for whichever target it's building for. At least that's what I think it's doing.

Comment: Are you sure you need `native` recipe? Do you compile something that will run on build machine? (I'm not talking about cross-compiling)? Maybe you only need `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " <package>-staticdev <package>-dev"` ?

Comment: @Nayfe Thanks, I've just had a silly moment, and you're completely right. If you create an answer from that last comment, I'll happy accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't need `native` part of recipe to run something on `host (build machine)` but `target` part, you should add the following line to add it to `SDK`:

```
 TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " <package>-staticdev <package>-dev"
```